# Response from ImagePicker doesn't contain Data

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-image-picker

My code snippet:

```
showImagePicker = () => {
    const options = {
        storageOptions: {
            skipBackup: true
        },
        mediaType: 'video',
        videoQuality: 'high',
        durationLimit: 10,
        allowsEditing: true,
        noData: false
    };

    ImagePicker.launchCamera(options, (response) => {
        console.warn('Object === ' + Object.keys(response))
        // Upload video to DB
        ...
    });
}
```

**Issue:**

*Response* doesn't contain anything but *path* and *uri*.

Even *noData:false* didn't help.

Testing OS is Android.

Comment: what do you want in response?

Comment: Response should contain **isVertical**. I need its value.

Comment: Are you using react-native-image-picker?

Comment: Correct. I've seen that base64 data is only available for photos but are there any workarounds to get **isVertical** option of a video? Dimensions of a video are also not available.